# Вектор пар в Java

Tags: java

Как создать вектор пар?

То есть, чтобы в i-ом элементе хранилось 2 значения.

Например, `a[2] = (1,3)`

Comment: Решений может быть много, все зависит от целей... Есть то, что называется multimap - это map , в которой одному ключу может соотвествовать несколько значений. берете целочисленный ключ и, собственно, все. Можете, например, прятать в обычный ArrayList массив на 2 элемента. Эта коллекция по сути является массивом, т.е. имеет индексы, ну а массив элементов внутри обеспечит вам хранение ваших данных. Можно написать собственный класс, причем тут полная свобода, в т.ч. с выбором возможного родителя... и так далее. Сформулируйте точнее задачу, тогда можно посоветовать что-то более конкретное.

Comment: В общем, есть строй из людей. У каждого человека есть 2(1) соседа. Вот и нужно хранить в a[i] человеке пару его соседей.

Comment: Ну, если я правильно понимаю, то сосед тоже не собака... По факту Вам нужно иметь класс , называемый условно Person, который будет хранить ссылку , а скорее даже коллекцию ссылок на самого себя. Ведь у соседа тоже есть сосед, нужна обратная связь, если можно так сказать

Comment: Простое решение - имитируйте работу БД. Создайте класс с нужными полями, добавьте туда id, а также коллекцию id соседей. Создайте Map, где id  будет ключ, а ваш класс значение. А потом все просто. Есть вася, у него id  1, есть петя , id  2, коля id  3. Вася сосед пети, значит в коллекцию объекта, который храит инфу о васе, добавляем id  пети и наоборот. Все эти классы в коллекции. Теперь , имея обеъкт с васей, вы имеете в коллекции id  всех его соседей, а раз id  есть ключ в Map, то найти и получить объекты всех соседей не составляет труда.

Comment: `ArrayList<Pair>`, где `Pair` -- класс с двумя полями.